# handleActionWithIdentifier when app isn't launched

Tags: ios, ios9, uilocalnotification

I've been using interactive notification and it works well when my app is suspended in the background, but causes problems when my app has been terminated.

I've used NSLog to determine the app's lifecycle when the interactive notification is triggered when the app has not launched.

The following goes on, in the order listed, without the app visibly launching:

didfinishlaunching
handleActionWithIdentifier
viewdidload
viewwilllayoutsubviews
viewdidlayoutsubviews
viewdidappear

The app then seems to terminate without calling
didenterbackground or willTerminate

The reason why it's causing issues for me is because I create timers in viewdidload that are invalidated in didenterbackground.

Because didenterbackground isn't being called, when the app is subsequently launched after triggering an interactive notification I'm ending up with two instances of the timer.

Could anyone shed some light on why the app terminates but didenterbackground or willTerminate aren't being called?

Comment: Because your app is launched directly into the background. It doesn't transition from foreground to background

Answer (score 0):

You should not assume that a call to didfinishlaunching means that you are in the foreground. As @PaulW11 says in his comment, for local notifications when your app is not running, you get launched directly into the background, and never see a foreground-to-background transition, because you were never in the foreground in the first place.

The system will call `applicationDidBecomeActive:` if you are being launched into the foreground. You should put your code that starts your timers there.

The docs say that local notification notices get invoked in the background:

> When the user taps a custom action in the alert for a remote or local
>   notification’s, the system calls the
>   application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:
>   or
>   application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:
>   method in the background so that your app can perform the associated
>   action.

You should write your `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:` method to check to see if it's being called from the foreground or from the background.

I use (Objective-C) code like this to tell if I'm in the foreground or the background:

```
BOOL inBackground = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground;
```